# Не запускается код PyQt5. Ошибка -1073740771

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.5, pyqt

При сборке `PyQt` из `ui` (при чём собрался только класс, запуск пришлось добавлять самому)

```
from PyQt5 import QtQuickWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Приложение не запустилось, появился диалог `"python не отвечает"` и всё завершилось ошибкой в консоли:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить этот код в ваш файл. Он позволит поймать исключение, которое сломало скрипт и показать точное место с ошибкой:

```
import sys    
import traceback

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

...
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Код в вопросе не мог вызвать ту ошибку, и я думаю что она произошла в `ui.setupUi(Form)`, но т.к. нет полного кода, то думаю имеет смысл хотя бы показать инструмент для отлова таких ошибок.