# Pithon exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui

**Вводные**: Win 10 64bit, Python 3.9, PyQt5, Gui.
Программа завершается с `exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)`
В трассировке никаких ошибок не выводится. Можно ли как то выловить это исключение с помощью try-except?

**Из наблюдений**: приблизительный фрагмент кода, в котором сидит проблема, выявил. Но он выполняется без ошибок. В режиме отладки построчно выполнял код и после проблемного участка он тоже нормально выполняется. Но когда все строки кода в проблемной функции выполнены - скидывает на `exit(App.exec())`

**Дополнение от 29.03.2023**: заметил что вылет происходит после смены иерархии/родителей `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. Но не в момент смены, а по завершении любой из функций, в которой происходит эта смена иерархии. Так как код после переназначения родителя выполняется до конца функции.

**Дополнение от 10.04.2023:**
В windows данный код говорит **STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION**, что означает `The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.` В моем случае.

Проще говоря - проблемы с обращением к ячейкам памяти. Допускаю, что они связаны со сборщиком мусора, но вероятнее всего с удалением объектов, являющихся родительскими по отношению к другим.

В коде есть функция, удаляющая итемы из сцены, при их удалении удаляются соответственно и их дочерние итемы. Предполагаю, что PyQt5 по каким то причинам не выводит ошибку в отладчик, **когда удаляется итем уничтоженный ранее вместе с родителем**. И прога падает.
То есть невозможно обращение к адресу памяти, который уже не существует.
Надеюсь, осталось понять каким образом определить какие итемы в сцене присутствуют (были добавлены методом `additem`).

Comment: Возможные ответы: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306673/pyqt-crashes-when-trying-to-show-opencv-videostream) [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456891/pyqt-crashes-after-sleep) [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734262/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-pyqt5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-1073740771)

Comment: Не нужно добавлять числа в метки вопроса.

Comment: @АнонимныйПаша Ни один не помогает (( И ошибку не поймать. Нашел только в ссылках тех ответов, что иерархия объектов может вызывать сбой, у меня как раз при смене иерархии сбой и происходит.
И еще интересная особенность: переписываю функцию иначе, при первом запуске все работает, а при последующих опять вылетает.

Comment: Что такое "смена иерархии"?

Comment: @CrazyElf QGraphicsPixmapItem.setParentItem(). Он работает как контейнер, поэтому любому QGraphicsPixmapItem можно назначить родителем другой QGraphicsPixmapItem.

Comment: Что же, пришло время показать код. Тяжело, но надо

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Нереально))) 3 модуля, основной скрипт около 4000 строк, переназначение классов около 2000 и дополнительный с функциями около 4000. Все переплетены между собой. Пытался выделить основное в отдельный скрипт, чтоб воспроизвести проблему, по факту оказалось что это почти половина задействованных переменных и почти весь импорт библиотек.
Поэтому и спросил, может как то можно выловить эти экситы? Трай-эксцепт не ловит, хуки тоже(( Логирование аналогично не помогает(

Comment: Значит ничем помочь не можем. Удачи

Answer (score 0):

**Решение в данном случае:**

Не считаю этот способ решением общей проблемы `exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)`, но в конкретном случае это действительно решение.

Вычитал на [англоязычных ресурсах](https://www.programmersought.com/article/362310779592/) решение. Такое падение программы возникает при логарифмическом методе индексации объектов `QGraphicsItem` в сцене. Падает программа при удалении объектов со сцены.
Причину не могу объяснить и не нашел нигде объяснений.
Но проблема устраняется при изменении метода индексации объектов в сцене `setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)`

[Более подробно в документации.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#itemIndexMethod-prop)